# How to get the recent registered record from database using dataset in between two given date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dataset

How to get the recent registered records from database using dataset in c#. I want to get the recent registered data between two given date and generate the report.

My table it like this on the Database
[See image -Table in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P58ej.jpg)

```
Id        Refno       TradingName                       Seta                   TransactionDate           SetaLevy    SetaAdmin     SetaInterest   SetaPenalty  TotalSetaCollected   SchemeYear

70112109  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   -15918,12   -2404,9       0              0            -18323,02            2013

70200624  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   -2805,75    -423,89       0              0            -3229,64             2013

70239219  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-02-01 00:00:00.000   -178917,65  -27030,73     0              0            -205948,38           2013

70320888  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-02-01 00:00:00.000   -2734,63    -413,15       0              0            -3147,78             2013

70368752  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-03-01 00:00:00.000   -68072,97   -10284,41     0              0            -78357,38            2013

70450502  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000   -2563,18    -387,24       -2,75          -295,04      -3248,21             2013

70575355  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -2671,44    -403,6        -0,72          -307,5       -3383,26             2013

70575014  L380706855  BONITO DISTRIBUTORS CC            WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -490,42     -74,09        -0,26          -56,75       -621,52              2013

70489231  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -17112,97   -2585,41       0             0            -19698,38            2013

70972265  L380706855  BONITO DISTRIBUTORS CC            WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   224,18      33,87          -0,59         -33,44       224,02               2013

70972585  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -15697,31   -2371,54        0            0            -18068,85            2014

71071473  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -2727,84    -412,12         0            0            -3139,96             2014

70932675  L740753381  KOREAN JOURNAL                    PUBLIC SECTOR          2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -152,68     -21,81          0            0            -174,49              2011
```

My current code is like this

```
public DataSet getRecentRegistrations(DateTime startMonth, DateTime endMonth, long setaCode)
{
   var query = (from _transaction in
   _entities.LevyTransactions
   join _seta in _entities.Setas on _transaction.SetaCode equals _seta.SetaCode

 join company_details in _entities.Organisations on _transaction.Refno equals company_details.Refno

 where(_transaction.TransactionDate >= startMonth || startMonth == null)

 && (_transaction.TransactionDate <= endMonth || endMonth == null)

 && (_transaction.SetaCode == setaCode || setaCode < 0)

 select new

   {
     SetaCode = _transaction.SetaCode,

     RefNo = company_details.Refno,
     TradingName = company_details.TradingName,              
     Seta = _transaction.SetaCode+" - "+_seta.Description,
     SetaLevy = _transaction.SetaLevy,
     SetaInterest = _transaction.SetaInterest,
     SetaAdmin = _transaction.SetaAdmin,

     SetaPenalty = _transaction.SetaPenalty,
     TotalSetaCollected = _transaction.TotalSetaCollected
   });

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable());ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";  
ds.Tables.Add(headerTable("Transaction Month From : "

 +HelperService.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", startMonth) + " To :"

 + HelperService.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", endMonth),"Recently Registered Companies")); 

ds.Tables[1].TableName ="Table2";
var setaRows = (from DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows
select new { SetaCode = dRow["SetaCode"], Seta = dRow["Seta"]}).Distinct();

ds.Tables.Add(setaRows.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[2].TableName = "Table3";
    return ds;
    }
```

My current out put on the report is just giving me all record that are found in between two date but what is needed to be out put is the new registered record only.

So my current out put is like this.

**Recently Registered from: *2014-04-01 -2014-05-01***

```
Id        Refno       TradingName                       Seta                   TransactionDate           SetaLevy    SetaAdmin     SetaInterest   SetaPenalty  TotalSetaCollected   SchemeYear

70575355  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -2671,44    -403,6        -0,72          -307,5       -3383,26             2013

70575014  L380706855  BONITO DISTRIBUTORS CC            WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -490,42     -74,09        -0,26          -56,75       -621,52              2013

70489231  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -17112,97   -2585,41       0             0            -19698,38            2013

70972265  L380706855  BONITO DISTRIBUTORS CC            WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   224,18      33,87          -0,59         -33,44       224,02               2013

70972585  L760732281  GOLDMAN SACHS INTERNATIONAL       BANKING                2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -15697,31   -2371,54        0            0            -18068,85            2014

71071473  L250734490  TROPICANA IMPORTERS & EXPORTERS   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -2727,84    -412,12         0            0            -3139,96             2014

70932675  L740753381  KOREAN JOURNAL                    PUBLIC SECTOR          2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -152,68     -21,81          0            0            -174,49              2011
```

The out put suppose to be like this shown on the image below

**Recently Registered from: *2014-04-01 -2014-05-01***

```
Id          Refno       TradingName              Seta                  TransactionDate           SetaLevy   SetaAdmin   SetaInterest    SetaPenalty     TotalSetaCollected   SchemeYear
70575014    L380706855  BONITO DISTRIBUTORS CC   WHOLESALE AND RETAIL  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -490,42    -74,09      -0,26           -56,75          -621,52              2013
70932675    L740753381  KOREAN JOURNAL           PUBLIC SECTOR         2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -152,68    -21,81      0               0               -174,49              2011
```

[See image -Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhRF1.jpg)

Please help me.

Comment: There isn't a column in the table that indicates which account are "new registered" so how is the code going to know which account are new?

Comment: @Dlamini.M: How are you supposed to know what a new record is?

Comment: @ jdweng no there is no column that indicate that is new registered it what confusing me how can I tell the computer to ignore those record that their Refno is existing before starting date. I was thinking of using a store procedure in sql but still I have same problem.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales I think if  I can check that  Refno is existing before starting date. Then if Refno existing the computer should skip that record, else display those Refno that do not exist before Start Date. Do you have any idea that how can I check?

Comment: I solved it now it works. `&& !_entities.LevyTransactions.Where(y => y.TransactionDate < startMonth)
                                .Select(y => y.OrgId).Contains(_transaction.OrgId)`